# SQL Add values to rows from another table

Tags: sql

I'm having problems getting a SQL query to insert data into a column from another table. Whenever I do it it adds the date as extra rows rather than in the rows that match.

Here is an example:

TABLE A

| ID | DATE | WEIGHTING |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 971 | 3/6/21 |  |
| 972 | 3/6/21 |  |
| 973 | 3/6/21 |  |

TABLE B

| ID | DLTID | WEIGHTING |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4441 | 971 | .03 |
| 4443 | 972 | .05 |
| 4445 | 973 | .01 |

Join TABLE A on B.DTLID = A.ID

I need to populate the A.Weighting column with values from B.Weighting, matched on A.ID = B.DLTID. The tables have millions of rows. Hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: tag your dbms as well

Comment: And show the code you are using -- as text -- in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
update TableA
set WEIGHTING = B.WEIGHTING
from tableB B
where B.DTLID = TableA.ID
```

and to improve the performance of this update , you can add an index on TableB (DTLID, WEIGHTING)